# Group Policy Drive Maps not mapping some network drives

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

On our Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller, we have a GPO named "IT Mapped Network Drives". "IT Mapped Network Drives" contains two Drive Maps, V: drive and Z: drive.

[image]

"IT Mapped Network Drives" is in our **software.eng.apl** domain, and members of the IT group should have access to IT Mapped Network Drives.

[image]

Jeremy Canfield is a member of the IT group.

[image]

When Jeremy Canfield signs into a Windows 10 PC which has joined the software.eng.apl domain, only one of the two mapped network drives appears in File Explorer. I am not certain why only one of the two mapped network drives appears, and I am also not certain what needs to be done to get both mapped network drives to map on the client PC.

[image]

If it helps, both of these network drives are on Linux machines and are being shared using Samba. This part of my post is more appropriate for Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, but just in case it helps, I would like to point out that both of these shared network drives have an identical configuration file in Linux, so I doubt the configuration of Samba on the Linux machines is the cause of the issue. Here is the configuration on Linux:

```
[global]
workgroup = APL
security = ADS
realm = software.eng.apl
password server = software.eng.apl
passdb backend = tbdsam

[share]
path = /srv/samba/share
browsable = yes
public = yes
writeable = yes
```

Comment: Does the problem only occur on the one client PC? What happens if you change the GPP drive mapping action to Update? Can you manually map the drive?

Comment: The problem occurs on every client PC. I changed the drive mapping to Update, restarted the client, and still the drive in question is not mapped. I can manually map the drive.

Comment: Can you flip flop the drive mappings and see what happens? (I.e. Make V: into Z: and vice versa)

Comment: Also, anything logged in the event logs on login?

Comment: Your flip flop suggestion helped me find the issue!  I noticed the Linux server with the mapped network drive that is not mapping is not listed in Computers in Active Directory Users and Computers. I'll need to configure Kerberos on the Linux server so that it can be added to the Windows Domain Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the problem is due to the configuration of the group policy drive map preference item, or the connection to the server being mapped.

A simply way to troubleshoot this would be to swap the drive letters of the two mappings.  In other words, change the mapping for drive `V:` to `Z:` and vice-versa.

If the problem persists (drive V: still doesn't get mapped), then the problem is likely with the choice of drive letter itself.  Perhaps there is something on the client machines that's not allowing use of drive V:.

If the V: drive starts working but Z: stops working, then the issue is with the connection to the remote share. It's possible there is a credential or authentication issue with the connection.